# How to close connection with Mariaex and Elixir

Tags: mysql, elixir

I am using the `Mariaex.start_link` method to establish a connection with MySQL database and it returns me a pid. I was wondering what's the best practice to manage these pids, i.e. close and create new ones every time? keep `1, 2, ... n` pid(s) around as needed?

Also how would I close that connection or kill that pid? I tried `Process.exit` with `:normal` which doesn't stop it and I tried it with `:kill` but I get an error probably from Mariaex and it doesn't seem clean to kill it that way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might refer to [`Ecto`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/) codebase to see how it [handles this case](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.2.6/lib/ecto/adapters/mysql.ex#L283-L289).

Basically, it starts a connection, executes a query and stops the `Mariaex` `GenServer` immediately after:

```
with {:ok, conn} <- Mariaex.start_link(opts) do
  value = Ecto.Adapters.MySQL.Connection.execute(conn, sql, [], opts)
  GenServer.stop(conn)
  value
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the response: it gives me an idea. Another thing though is I haven't gone through supervisor and/or `GenServer` from the tutorials yet. I am just starting with a very basic project. Is `GenServer` a reference I can get from `Mariaex` or do I have to set the project up to work with GenServer from the get go?

Comment: `Mariaex` _is_ a `GenServer` itself. There is no way to implement anything meaningful in Elixir without understanding basic OTP principles, specifically without understanding what `GenServer` is.

Comment: Ok sounds good. I figured. I'll just keep on going through The Little Elixir and OTP Guidebook then. Thanks!

Comment: “The Little Elixir and OTP Guidebook”—This is a good choice :)